# (debian) installing mod_qos on apache results in error on start

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, dynamic-loading

I installed the mod_qos module using the steps found [here](http://pc-freak.net/blog/quick-way-to-install-mod_qos-on-debian-lenny-to-protect-from-slowloris/), every step went perfectly fine without any problems, however, when attempting to restart the apache service it returned the following error:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 203 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/qos.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_qos.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_qos.so: undefined symbol: EVP_DecryptFinal
```

The contents of the qos.load file is just this line:

```
LoadModule qos_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_qos.so
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that mod_qos is trying to use a part of a library that is not (yet) loaded or available. EVP_DecryptFinal should be a part of openSSL, so provided that you've got mod_ssl installed, try loading it **before** you load qos.

Comment: mod_ssl is installed and working, how can I make sure it's loaded before loading mod_qos? would renaming ssl.load -> 0.load and qos.load -> 1.load work?

Comment: that actually seems to have solved the problem